# How to generate a signed PDF w/o green checkmark

Tags: java, pdf, itext, signature

I'm signing PDF's using iText. I'm including a graphic in the signature. This works, but the green checkmark (or yellow question mark) that shows when the document is verified interferes with the graphic I inserted, making the end result look ugly.

It either shows up above or below the signature graphic, but I can't get it to disappear.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Reader 9 changes this behavior.  The individual signature statuses were removed in favor of a global signature status which appears just above the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry but I don't understand this. You want a valid signature but no possibility to see that the signature is valid? Doesn't make sense to me.

Anyway, I think the green checkmark is rendered by Adobe Reader so you will have no chance to remove it.

Comment: The signature will stay say "Valid Signature (in text)", but without the checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to get around this is to remove the existing signature block and apply your image in its place.  Then, sign the PDF with an invisible signature.  This will still allow the user to open the signature sidebar to verify that the signature is valid.

Comment: yes, but it also means that the image is visible even if the signature is invalid.