# checkmark when pdf signed with iText

Tags: itext, digital-signature

I'm signing PDFs using iText. 
And I include a graphic representation of the signature in the document.

This works, but the green checkmark (or yellow question mark) that shows when the document is verified interferes with the graphic I inserted, making the end result look ugly.

Is there a way to manage the size of the green checkbox?
Are there any properties, fonts, image scale, etc that dictate the size of this green check mark?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate a signed PDF w/o green checkmark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367965/how-to-generate-a-signed-pdf-w-o-green-checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

The checkmark is rendered by the PDF reader.  Please see [How to generate a signed PDF w/o green checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367965/how-to-generate-a-signed-pdf-w-o-green-checkmark) for more information.